# eWay iframe payment getway intigration

Tags: payment-gateway

I have downloaded eway API (https://github.com/eWAYPayment/eway-rapid-php).
And As per this document https://eway.io/api-v3/#iframe I have intigrated eway iframe payment method.

In test mode I am generating payment URL using this
This is test API key

```
$apiKey = 'A1001CySeCsbAow/FB71ofmbG9puc5iqoaTM4WnSjcTrUP74qFWQzYoaJm34yS9k4pu8MK';
$apiPassword = 'MpFW18pu';
$apiEndpoint = 'Sandbox';

$client = \Eway\Rapid::createClient($apiKey, $apiPassword, $apiEndpoint);
```

All work well I am able to pay on eway and get proper transaction ID and all that,

Now I want to make it live so I have chnaged live API key and Password but what should I add in endpoint?
I have try all URL they suggest in this document https://eway.io/api-v3/#iframe

```
SOAP    https://api.ewaypayments.com/soap.asmx
SOAP WSDL   https://api.ewaypayments.com/soap.asmx?WSDL
REST (POST) https://api.ewaypayments.com/AccessCodesShared
HTTP POST (XML) https://api.ewaypayments.com/CreateAccessCodeShared.xml
HTTP POST (JSON)    https://api.ewaypayments.com/CreateAccessCodeShared.json
RPC (XML)   https://api.ewaypayments.com/xml-rpc
RPC (JSON)  https://api.ewaypayments.com/json-rpc
```

But error say invalid API key or Password but I am 100% sure that it's currect as I have also intigrated 
https://eway.io/api-v3/#transparent-redirect this payment method using same credential. so it's something to do with end point.

in there document they provide this URL for sandbox testing

```
SOAP    https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/soap.asmx
SOAP WSDL   https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/soap.asmx?WSDL
REST (POST) https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/AccessCodesShared
HTTP POST (XML) https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/CreateAccessCodeShared.xml
HTTP POST (JSON)    https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/CreateAccessCodeShared.json
RPC (XML)   https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/xml-rpc
RPC (JSON)  https://api.sandbox.ewaypayments.com/json-rpc
```

I have used one by one in my sandbox test which was working and now it also display same error. I really need help here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `production` when you go live (along with your production API key and password of course).

This should have been made more clear in the docs and will updated in the next couple of days.

For those curious, this is defined in the [Rapid Client contract](https://github.com/eWAYPayment/eway-rapid-php/blob/6b9dcc157079048bd4adb58e7b90dcd29f7dbd13/src/Rapid/Contract/Client.php#L41).